# How to use the function option of org-capture correctly?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to dynamically open the correct file in an orgmode capture template using the `function` option:

```
("a" "foo" plain
    (function my-visit-timestamped-file)
    "<some content>")
```

Function `my-visit-timestamped-file` is defined as

```
(defun my-visit-timestamped-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let
      ((theDate (format-time-string "%Y%m%d-%H%M.org")))
  (find-file (concat "<some_path>" theDate))))
```

If I run the capture template `a`, emacs opens the file `<some_path>theDate` in a buffer and opens the capture buffer with the file.
Thus my window is split into 2 buffers showing the same content.

Can function `my-visit-timestamped-file` be changed somehow such that the buffer is not opened but org capture still gets the correct file pointer/file handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @jpkotta pointed me in the right direction.
The bug was gone, but instead the content of the capture buffer was always pasted into the buffer I was currently editing.

In an old thread on the org-mode mailing list I found the answer to my question. The function should be:

```
(defun my-visit-timestamped-file ()
  "Visit a new file named by the current timestamp"
  (interactive)
  (let* (
        (curr-date-stamp (format-time-string "%Y%m%d-%H%M.org"))
        (file-name (expand-file-name curr-date-stamp "/some/path/")))
  (set-buffer (org-capture-target-buffer file-name))
  (goto-char (point-max))))
```

Link to mailing list thread: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-11/msg00676.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `find-file-noselect` instead of `find-file`.  Note that the docs of `org-capture-templates` say this:

```
         (function function-finding-location)
            Most general way: write your own function which both visits
            the file and moves point to the right location
```

so you might want to add some code to go to the correct location (I'm guessing either `(point-min)` or `(point-max)`) in the file.  That might look like this:

```
(defun my-visit-timestamped-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((the-date (format-time-string "%Y%m%d-%H%M.org"))
         (the-buffer (find-file-noselect (expand-file-name the-date "/some/path/"))))
    (with-current-buffer the-buffer
      (goto-char (point-min)))
    the-buffer))
```

Comment: Thanks. `find-file-noselect` was exactly what I was looking for.